# How to monitor dead relus

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I think I might have a problem with dead Relus, but I don't really know how to check it with tensorboard or any other way. Your help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Maybe evaluate all neuron activated by relu by doing a (partial) forward pass and check which of them are output zeros?

Answer (score 3):

I initially had this same question myself and couldn't find an answer, so here's how I'm doing it with Tensorboard (This assumes some familiarity with Tensorboard).

```
activation = tf.nn.relu(layer) 
active = tf.count_nonzero(tf.count_nonzero(activation, axis=0))
tf.summary.scalar('pct-active-neurons', active / layer.shape[1])
```

In this snip, `activation` is my post-ReLU activation for this particular layer. The first call to `tf.count_nonzero(out, axis=0)` is counting how many activations each neuron has seen across all training examples for the current step of training. The second call `tf.count_nonzero( ... )` that wraps the first call counts how many neurons in the layer had at least one activation for the batch of training examples for this step. Finally, I convert it to a percentage by dividing the number of neurons that had at least one activation in the training step by the total number of neurons for the layer.

More information on setting up Tensorboard can be found [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/summaries_and_tensorboard).

Answer (score 1):

How about adding the summary 

`tf.summary.scalar('%s/fraction_of_zero_values' % tag, tf.nn.zero_fraction(value))`