# Minimal diffusion model (DDIM) for MNIST

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

For the purpose of learning I created a minimal DDIM for the MNIST dataset. Everything besides the math of diffusions I consider "extras."

Here is the list of extras:

- U-Net
- Positional embeddings
- Diffusion Schedule
- Normalization of the dataset
- Exponential Moving Averages

The reason for a minimal example is because I do not understand the contribution of these other tricks. Therefore, If I start with something simpler - I can see the contribution of additional optimizations.

Simplifying the network, IMO is also a generalization step and therefore the methodology can be applied to other problems.

The code is borrowed from this great Keras example: https://keras.io/examples/generative/ddim/

**Just to clarify, to answer this question one can either provide a network that is simpler than u-net that we can recognize some digits, or explain why we need u-net**.

I read something interesting from the original author in the Keras blog under the architectural tips. It says:

> **skip connections**: Using skip connections in the network architecture
> is absolutely critical, without them the model will fail to learn to
> denoise at a good performance.

**Code - updated to remove all extras**:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os

print("tf version: ", tf.__version__)

# data
diffusion_steps = 20
image_size = 28

# sampling
min_signal_rate = 0.02
max_signal_rate = 0.95

# optimization
batch_size = 64
num_epochs = 1000
learning_rate = 1e-3

embedding_dims = 32
embedding_max_frequency = 1000.0


x0 = tf.keras.Input(shape=(28, 28, 1))
t0 = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1, 1, 1))

combined = tf.keras.layers.Add()([x0, t0])

x = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(combined)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(7 * 7 * 64, activation="relu")(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((7, 7, 64))(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(
    64, 3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same"
)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(
    32, 3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same"
)(x)
output = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(1, 3, activation="sigmoid", padding="same")(x)
network = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[x0, t0], outputs=output)
print(network.summary())


class DiffusionModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, network):
        super().__init__()

        self.normalizer = tf.keras.layers.Normalization()
        self.network = network

    def compile(self, **kwargs):
        super().compile(**kwargs)
        self.noise_loss_tracker = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name="n_loss")
        self.image_loss_tracker = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name="i_loss")

    @property
    def metrics(self):
        return [self.noise_loss_tracker, self.image_loss_tracker]

    def denormalize(self, images):
        return tf.clip_by_value(images, 0.0, 1.0)

    # predictive stage
    def denoise(self, noisy_images, times, training):
        # predict noise component and calculate the image component using it
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            tape.watch(noisy_images)
            pred_noises = self.network([noisy_images, times**2], training=training)
            gradients = tape.gradient(pred_noises, noisy_images)
        pred_images = noisy_images - pred_noises - gradients
        return pred_noises, pred_images

    def reverse_diffusion(self, initial_noise, steps):
        # reverse diffusion = sampling
        batch = initial_noise.shape[0]
        step_size = 1.0 / steps
        
        next_noisy_images = initial_noise
        next_diffusion_times = tf.ones((batch, 1, 1, 1))

        for step in range(diffusion_steps):
            noisy_images = next_noisy_images
            diffusion_times = next_diffusion_times

            pred_noises, pred_images = self.denoise(
                noisy_images, diffusion_times, training=False
            )

            # this new noisy image will be used in the next step
            next_diffusion_times = diffusion_times - step_size
            next_noisy_images = pred_images + pred_noises
        return pred_images

    def generate(self, num_images, steps):
        # noise -> images -> denormalized images
        initial_noise = tf.random.normal(shape=(num_images, image_size, image_size, 1))
        generated_images = self.reverse_diffusion(initial_noise, steps)
        return generated_images

    def train_step(self, images):
        noises = tf.random.normal(shape=(batch_size, image_size, image_size, 1))
        diffusion_times = tf.random.uniform(
            shape=(batch_size, 1, 1, 1), minval=0.0, maxval=1.0
        )

        with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
            noisy_images = images + noises
            # train the network to separate noisy images to their components
            pred_noises, pred_images = self.denoise(
                noisy_images, diffusion_times, training=True
            )

            noise_loss = self.loss(noises, pred_noises)  # used for training
            image_loss = self.loss(images, pred_images)  # only used as metric
            
            # total_loss = noise_loss + image_loss

        gradients = tape.gradient(noise_loss, self.network.trainable_weights)
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, self.network.trainable_weights))

        self.noise_loss_tracker.update_state(noise_loss)
        self.image_loss_tracker.update_state(image_loss)
        return {m.name: m.result() for m in self.metrics}

    def plot_images(
        self,
        epoch=None,
        logs=None,
        num_rows=3,
        num_cols=6,
        write_to_file=True,
        output_dir="output",
    ):
        # plot random generated images for visual evaluation of generation quality
        generated_images = self.generate(
            num_images=num_rows * num_cols,
            steps=diffusion_steps,
        )

        plt.figure(figsize=(num_cols * 2.0, num_rows * 2.0))
        for row in range(num_rows):
            for col in range(num_cols):
                index = row * num_cols + col
                plt.subplot(num_rows, num_cols, index + 1)
                plt.imshow(generated_images[index])
                plt.axis("off")

        plt.tight_layout()

        if write_to_file:
            if not os.path.exists(output_dir):
                os.makedirs(output_dir)
            if epoch is not None:
                filename = os.path.join(
                    output_dir, "image_epoch_{:04d}.png".format(epoch)
                )
            else:
                import time

                timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
                filename = os.path.join(output_dir, "image_{}.png".format(timestr))
            plt.savefig(filename)
        else:
            plt.show()

        plt.close()


# create and compile the model
model = DiffusionModel(network)
model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.experimental.AdamW(learning_rate=learning_rate),
    # loss=tf.keras.losses.mean_squared_error,
    loss=tf.keras.losses.mean_absolute_error,
)
# pixelwise mean absolute error is used as loss

# save the best model based on the noise loss
checkpoint_path = "checkpoints/diffusion_model"
checkpoint_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
    filepath=checkpoint_path,
    save_weights_only=True,
    monitor="n_loss",
    mode="min",
    save_best_only=True,
)

(x_train, _), (x_test, _) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
mnist_digits = np.concatenate([x_train, x_test], axis=0)
mnist_digits = np.expand_dims(mnist_digits, -1).astype("float32") / 255

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(mnist_digits)
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size, drop_remainder=True)
dataset = dataset.shuffle(10000, reshuffle_each_iteration=True)


# run training and plot generated images periodically
model.fit(
    dataset,
    epochs=num_epochs,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    callbacks=[
        tf.keras.callbacks.LambdaCallback(on_epoch_end=model.plot_images),
        checkpoint_callback,
    ],
)

# load the best model and generate images
model.load_weights(checkpoint_path)
model.plot_images(write_to_file=False)
```

**Update 1**

I removed all "extras" listed above including the scheduler and normalizer - and changed the denoising method to take the derivative of the predicted noise with respect to the noisy images.

```
def denoise(self, noisy_images, times, training):
    # predict noise component and calculate the image component using it
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        tape.watch(noisy_images)
        pred_noises = self.network([noisy_images, times**2], training=training)
        gradients = tape.gradient(pred_noises, noisy_images)
    pred_images = noisy_images - pred_noises - gradients
    return pred_noises, pred_images
```

The result of this was that you could see there was something there (numbers) instead of just noise. So this hint of hope and the improvements suggested by the kind people below led to more improvements.

**Fixes**

- Removed commented out block as pointed out by @xdurch0
- Fixed denormalize method as pointed out by @Maciej Skorski
- Added a skip connection in update-2 as suggest by @Daraan and the remark from the original code author

**Update 2**

The biggest change that made the most difference was adding the skip connection. The input x, and t are multiplied together, flattened and to a dense layer with 'linear' activation function. This was very important. Then the dense layer is added to the output of the network. I think this helps the vanishing gradient but there may be more to it.

```
x0 = tf.keras.Input(shape=(28, 28, 1))
t0 = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1, 1, 1))

combined = tf.keras.layers.Add()([x0, t0])
x = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(combined)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(784, activation="linear")(x)
x1 = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((28, 28, 1))(x)

x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(7 * 7 * 64, activation="relu")(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((7, 7, 64))(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(
    64, 3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same"
)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(
    32, 3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same"
)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(1, 3, activation="relu", padding="same")(x)

output = tf.keras.layers.Add()([x, x1])
network = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[x0, t0], outputs=output)
```

With just this relatively small network and the "gradient trick" I was able to get here which was well beyond my initial goal.

[image]

Next, I added normalization and scheduler. The normalization emphasis the pixels - makes them more dense at the higher values. The scheduler helps with training. So the final results are as follows:

1. One skip connection, normalization, scheduler, and the "gradient trick"

[image]

2. One skip connection, normalization, scheduler, without the "gradient trick" - similar training parameters.

[image]

I think these results are great. In image generation there is a need for high fidelity but okay results like these can be useful in other fields. The gradient trick - that I made up by trial and error really surprised me. I would love to hear any thoughts from any researcher or academic that happens to see this.

Comment: This is really a bit much to be answered on this site (i.e. the minimal example is not very minimal). I would suggest you start with a working example and work your way "down" from there, i.e. remove components _one-by-one_ which you think are "not crucial". There are some questionable assumptions here, e.g. commenting out a block of code that you say "is not used at all" even though it is...

Comment: @xdurch0 Thank you so much for your comment. Indeed the block of commented code is my mistake. I just realized it is inside the diffusion loop.

Comment: Does it have to be tensorflow or are you okay with pytorch as well?

Comment: UNET can be slow to train. Your current architecture has >2M parameters in a wide dense layer. Try to avoid the dense any maybe just do a stack of convolution layers instead.

Comment: Guys, don't be that pessimistic but take the challenge! "too much to be answered on this site" this is a comment that should never appear on SO :-)

Comment: @EdvBeq I think I have spotted some mistakes and overall recommend the strategy of narrowing the working implementation (see my answer). Will try to bridge your code to the working state too.

Answer (score 0):

### General remark: go top-down

I would suggest going top-down.

Start eliminating the components from the working implementation, to see the consequences. In place of adding them on top of not working implementations.

Take [the official implementation by keras-team](https://colab.research.google.com/github/keras-team/keras-io/blob/master/examples/generative/ipynb/ddim.ipynb) which runs on **Colab which trains quickly on GPU**. I did **minor changes adapting to MNIST**, [this modified notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/maciejskorski/4dceff2f3044cf91550c5dae041c1178/ddim.ipynb) proves it **trains OK**.

Now, what would we like to remove?

### Problems with the current code

**NOTE (logic errors in the code)** I see some, for instance `denormalize` does not invert properly (ignores standard scaling). Commpare with the notebook I referenced.

**NOTE (under-performing code patterns)** `tf.dataset` can be used much more efficiently, compare with the notebook I referenced.

**NOTE (wrong architecture)** the proposed network is not coupled with `DiffusionModel`, for instance does not utilize noise rates.

**NOTE (performance tip)** for computer vision or large language models, I recommend running on Colab or Kaggle to get some free GPU bandwith.

### Working Code

I fixed issues with the diffusion code and connected to `ResUNet`, [this public notebook demonstrates it is working well](https://www.kaggle.com/code/mskorski/denoising-difussion-model).
Hence, we have narrowed the problem to the network implementation: it can also have mistakes or not be suitable.

Comment: It is correct that the code above its not inverting properly. Locally I have tried with proper scaling and without scaling - and still no success. I re-read the blog after your post - and the original author says that without skip connections the network will not learn the noise gradient at all. But, unfortunately does not explain why is the case.

Comment: @EdvBeq I have just demonstrated on Kaggle that your diffusion code - after fixes - works well with ResUNet (see my answer). Hence, I blame further mistakes in the network code.

Answer (score 0):

## Exponential Moving Averages - Student Teacher Networks and similar

Some use-case of EMA to understand it (here feature embedding):

For unsupervised learning Siamese and student-teacher-networks proved to be very useful for (pre-)training.
There are many variants, e.g. both have the same architecture, sometimes the teacher is a bigger network or has an easier task.
**The goal of the student is to predict the outcomes of the teacher network**. For pretraining the student network is the one wanted in the end.

Now think **how should this be optimized?**
Standard backpropagation would propagate the loss into both networks.
What would happen? The networks would only learn how to generate the same output (loss = 0), but ignore to create useful outputs.
**The solution EMA or momentum update:** Do only backpropagate into one network (the student) and adjust the second network slowly by adjusting the weights.

This is what happens here in the demo:

```
for weight, ema_weight in zip(self.network.weights, self.ema_network.weights):
            ema_weight.assign(ema * ema_weight + (1 - ema) * weight)
```

The update `ema * ema_weight + (1 - ema) * weight` updates the weights of the second network by a weighted average (or percentage) of the its old weights and the weights of the student network (which were updated via backpropagation).
**This allows to train two networks and (optimally) the student network becomes better than the teacher/ema-network and will be the final model.**

[image]

[image]
Image credits: Spyros Gidaris, Andrei Bursuc

---

## Normalization of the dataset

This is quite important if you work with **pretrained** networks, as they were trained on normalized datasets (e.g. ImageNet).
Aside from this normalization can help to make the training (at the start) more stable and it might converge faster.
From my experience on MNIST it does not matter much if you normalize it or not.

## Positional embedding and the diffusion process

# Needs improvement

The noise variant of the image is generated by mixing the image with the noise.

`noisy_images = signal_rates * images + noise_rates * noises`

Both rates are trigonometrical complements is obtained in the difission schedule (one by sin the other by cos).
This gives us the knowledge how much noise was added, which can be removed in the de-noising step:

```
pred_images = (noisy_images - noise_rates * pred_noises) / signal_rates
```

**The main idea is to iteratively generate a Gaussian noise from the input data, and reconstruct the input data from this Gaussian noise.
This allows to generate images from Gaussian noise.**

During the forward direction the noise is added iteratively to the original image:
[image]

[image]

In the reverse step the noise is iteratively removed again. How to do it is what the model learns, how to generate an image and separate the noise.

```
for step in range(diffusion_steps):
    # get the positional encoding
    noise_rates, signal_rates = self.diffusion_schedule(diffusion_times)    
    # Get the previous image without noise
    pred_noises, pred_images = self.denoise(
                noisy_images, noise_rates, signal_rates, training=False
            )
```

Image credits: [[4]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.11239.pdf) & [[5]](https://www.assemblyai.com/blog/diffusion-models-for-machine-learning-introduction/)

Useful sources:

https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.10739
https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.11239 (original paper)
https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.02502
https://www.assemblyai.com/blog/diffusion-models-for-machine-learning-introduction/

## UNet

A problem of deep networks is gradient vanishing. If the gradient is close to zero, the backpropagation will not update the weights anymore (or very slowly).
Image you have a layer that generates an output that is currently well fit, there is then no need to update its weights anymore; the gradient is zero. But what about the layers before it? Those will not be updated anymore.
With **skip-connections the model does learn how to modify its inputs (*out=f(in)+in*) instead of changing it (*out=f(in)*).
So even if the weights in *f* currently satisfy the loss (*f'(in)=0*), the loss can still be passed backwards because of the additional *+in*.

**UNet** is not so deep but the idea is similar, UNet learns how to modify the input via the encoding path to generate the same or a different output of the same size.
Secondly when removing the skip connections UNet is an autoencoder. autoencoders with a bottleneck can be used to denoise images.

Vaguely this is why the UNet architecture is usefull, remove noise and adjust the image.
Theoretically every structure with input=output is applicable.
Despite UNet being slow and bulky I haven't been able to make a simpler architecture that is as effective and efficient in the long run.

---

---

## Get the demo code running for MNIST

In principle one has to mainly look out for the channels and dimension:

### Dataset

(Note put this after the hyperparameters, but want to start with this)

```
# Cast it to 0...1 range and add the channel component [Batch, s, s, input_channels=1]
# The image will be upscaled because UNet works with multiples of 8 (afaik, 28 will not work)
image_size = 32
(x_train, _), (x_test, _) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
x_train = tf.cast(tf.clip_by_value(x_train / 255.0, 0.0, 1.0), tf.float32)
x_train = x_train[..., tf.newaxis] # expand by channel dimension
print(x_train.shape)
x_train = tf.image.resize(x_train, size=[image_size, image_size], antialias=True)


x_test = tf.cast(tf.clip_by_value(x_test / 255.0, 0.0, 1.0), tf.float32)
x_test  = x_test[..., tf.newaxis] # expand by channel dimension
x_test  = tf.image.resize(x_test, size=[image_size, image_size], antialias=True)

# Training is cheaper than validation adding a repeat here
x_train = (tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x_train)
             .batch(batch_size, drop_remainder=True)
             .repeat(3)
             .shuffle(10000, reshuffle_each_iteration=True)
             .prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
            )

# Validation is expensive, therefore I cut the size here in roughly half
x_test = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x_test[:5120]).batch(batch_size, drop_remainder=True).shuffle(10*batch_size).prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
```

### Hyperparameters

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
import os
#import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

from tensorflow import keras
layers = keras.layers

# data
num_epochs = 10  # at 10 epochs you should see if it works. train for at least 50 epochs for good results
image_size = 32  # multiple of 8
input_channels = 1  # NEW: for a different dataset it can be easily adjusted here

# KID = Kernel Inception Distance, see related section
kid_image_size =75 # has to be 75+
kid_diffusion_steps = 5
plot_diffusion_steps = 20

# sampling
min_signal_rate = 0.02
max_signal_rate = 0.95

# architecture
embedding_dims = 8*8  # TODO need to look into this again
embedding_max_frequency = 1000.0
widths = [32, 64, 96, 128]
block_depth = 2

# optimization
batch_size = 128  # Higher as the images are smaller
ema = 0.999
learning_rate = 1e-3
weight_decay = 1e-4
```

### Network architecture

The same as in the demo but accounts for `input_channels`

```py
def sinusoidal_embedding(x):
    embedding_min_frequency = 1.0
    frequencies = tf.exp(
        tf.linspace(
            tf.math.log(embedding_min_frequency),
            tf.math.log(embedding_max_frequency),
            embedding_dims // 2,
        )
    )
    angular_speeds = 2.0 * math.pi * frequencies
    embeddings = tf.concat(
        [tf.sin(angular_speeds * x), tf.cos(angular_speeds * x)], axis=-1
    )
    return embeddings


def ResidualBlock(width):
    def apply(x):
        input_width = x.shape[3]
        if input_width == width:
            residual = x
        else:
            residual = layers.Conv2D(width, kernel_size=1)(x)
        x = layers.BatchNormalization(center=False, scale=False)(x)
        x = layers.Conv2D(
            width, kernel_size=3, padding="same", activation=keras.activations.swish
        )(x)
        x = layers.Conv2D(width, kernel_size=3, padding="same")(x)
        x = layers.Add()([x, residual])
        return x

    return apply


def DownBlock(width, block_depth):
    def apply(x):
        x, skips = x
        for _ in range(block_depth):
            x = ResidualBlock(width)(x)
            skips.append(x)
        x = layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size=2)(x)
        return x

    return apply


def UpBlock(width, block_depth):
    def apply(x):
        x, skips = x
        x = layers.UpSampling2D(size=2, interpolation="bilinear")(x)
        for _ in range(block_depth):
            x = layers.Concatenate()([x, skips.pop()])
            x = ResidualBlock(width)(x)
        return x

    return apply


def get_network(image_size, widths, block_depth):
    noisy_images = keras.Input(shape=(image_size, image_size, input_channels))
    noise_variances = keras.Input(shape=(1, 1, 1))

    e = layers.Lambda(sinusoidal_embedding)(noise_variances)
    e = layers.UpSampling2D(size=image_size, interpolation="nearest")(e)

    x = layers.Conv2D(widths[0], kernel_size=1)(noisy_images)
    x = layers.Concatenate()([x, e])

    skips = []
    for width in widths[:-1]:
        x = DownBlock(width, block_depth)([x, skips])

    for _ in range(block_depth):
        x = ResidualBlock(widths[-1])(x)

    for width in reversed(widths[:-1]):
        x = UpBlock(width, block_depth)([x, skips])

    x = layers.Conv2D(input_channels, kernel_size=1, kernel_initializer="zeros")(x)

    return keras.Model([noisy_images, noise_variances], x, name="residual_unet")
```

### Diffusion Model

Adjusted with your plot function and input channels.

```py
class DiffusionModel(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, image_size, widths, block_depth):
        super().__init__()

        self.normalizer = layers.Normalization()
        self.network = get_network(image_size, widths, block_depth)
        self.ema_network = keras.models.clone_model(self.network)

    def compile(self, **kwargs):
        super().compile(**kwargs)

        self.noise_loss_tracker = keras.metrics.Mean(name="n_loss")
        self.image_loss_tracker = keras.metrics.Mean(name="i_loss")
        self.kid = KID(name="kid")

    @property
    def metrics(self):
        return [self.noise_loss_tracker, self.image_loss_tracker, self.kid]

    def denormalize(self, images):
        # convert the pixel values back to 0-1 range
        images = self.normalizer.mean + images * self.normalizer.variance**0.5
        return tf.clip_by_value(images, 0.0, 1.0)

    def diffusion_schedule(self, diffusion_times):
        # diffusion times -> angles
        start_angle = tf.acos(max_signal_rate)
        end_angle = tf.acos(min_signal_rate)

        diffusion_angles = start_angle + diffusion_times * (end_angle - start_angle)

        # angles -> signal and noise rates
        signal_rates = tf.cos(diffusion_angles)
        noise_rates = tf.sin(diffusion_angles)
        # note that their squared sum is always: sin^2(x) + cos^2(x) = 1

        return noise_rates, signal_rates

    def denoise(self, noisy_images, noise_rates, signal_rates, training):
        # the exponential moving average weights are used at evaluation
        if training:
            network = self.network
        else:
            network = self.ema_network

        # predict noise component and calculate the image component using it
        pred_noises = network([noisy_images, noise_rates**2], training=training)
        pred_images = (noisy_images - noise_rates * pred_noises) / signal_rates

        return pred_noises, pred_images

    def reverse_diffusion(self, initial_noise, diffusion_steps):
        # reverse diffusion = sampling
        num_images = initial_noise.shape[0]
        step_size = 1.0 / diffusion_steps

        # important line:
        # at the first sampling step, the "noisy image" is pure noise
        # but its signal rate is assumed to be nonzero (min_signal_rate)
        next_noisy_images = initial_noise
        for step in range(diffusion_steps):
            noisy_images = next_noisy_images

            # separate the current noisy image to its components
            diffusion_times = tf.ones((num_images, 1, 1, 1)) - step * step_size
            noise_rates, signal_rates = self.diffusion_schedule(diffusion_times)
            pred_noises, pred_images = self.denoise(
                noisy_images, noise_rates, signal_rates, training=False
            )
            # network used in eval mode

            # remix the predicted components using the next signal and noise rates
            next_diffusion_times = diffusion_times - step_size
            next_noise_rates, next_signal_rates = self.diffusion_schedule(
                next_diffusion_times
            )
            next_noisy_images = (
                next_signal_rates * pred_images + next_noise_rates * pred_noises
            )
            # this new noisy image will be used in the next step

        return pred_images

    def generate(self, num_images, diffusion_steps):
        # noise -> images -> denormalized images
        initial_noise = tf.random.normal(shape=(num_images, image_size, image_size, input_channels))
        generated_images = self.reverse_diffusion(initial_noise, diffusion_steps)
        generated_images = self.denormalize(generated_images)
        return generated_images

    def train_step(self, images):
        # normalize images to have standard deviation of 1, like the noises
        images = self.normalizer(images, training=True)
        noises = tf.random.normal(shape=(batch_size, image_size, image_size, input_channels))

        # sample uniform random diffusion times
        diffusion_times = tf.random.uniform(
            shape=(batch_size, 1, 1, 1), minval=0.0, maxval=1.0
        )
        noise_rates, signal_rates = self.diffusion_schedule(diffusion_times)
        # mix the images with noises accordingly
        noisy_images = signal_rates * images + noise_rates * noises

        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            # train the network to separate noisy images to their components
            pred_noises, pred_images = self.denoise(
                noisy_images, noise_rates, signal_rates, training=True
            )

            noise_loss = self.loss(noises, pred_noises)  # used for training
            image_loss = self.loss(images, pred_images)  # only used as metric

        gradients = tape.gradient(noise_loss, self.network.trainable_weights)
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, self.network.trainable_weights))

        self.noise_loss_tracker.update_state(noise_loss)
        self.image_loss_tracker.update_state(image_loss)

        # track the exponential moving averages of weights
        for weight, ema_weight in zip(self.network.weights, self.ema_network.weights):
            ema_weight.assign(ema * ema_weight + (1 - ema) * weight)

        # KID is not measured during the training phase for computational efficiency
        return {m.name: m.result() for m in self.metrics[:-1]}

    def test_step(self, images):
        # normalize images to have standard deviation of 1, like the noises
        images = self.normalizer(images, training=False)
        noises = tf.random.normal(shape=(batch_size, image_size, image_size, input_channels))

        # sample uniform random diffusion times
        diffusion_times = tf.random.uniform(
            shape=(batch_size, 1, 1, 1), minval=0.0, maxval=1.0
        )
        noise_rates, signal_rates = self.diffusion_schedule(diffusion_times)
        # mix the images with noises accordingly
        noisy_images = signal_rates * images + noise_rates * noises

        # use the network to separate noisy images to their components
        pred_noises, pred_images = self.denoise(
            noisy_images, noise_rates, signal_rates, training=False
        )

        noise_loss = self.loss(noises, pred_noises)
        image_loss = self.loss(images, pred_images)

        self.image_loss_tracker.update_state(image_loss)
        self.noise_loss_tracker.update_state(noise_loss)

        # measure KID between real and generated images
        # this is computationally demanding, kid_diffusion_steps has to be small
        images = self.denormalize(images)
        generated_images = self.generate(
            num_images=batch_size, diffusion_steps=kid_diffusion_steps
        )
        self.kid.update_state(images, generated_images)

        return {m.name: m.result() for m in self.metrics}

   def plot_images(
        self,
        epoch=None,
        logs=None,
        num_rows=2,
        num_cols=6,
        write_to_file=True,
        output_dir="output",
    ):
        # plot random generated images for visual evaluation of generation quality
        generated_images = self.generate(
            num_images=num_rows * num_cols,
            diffusion_steps=plot_diffusion_steps,
        )

        plt.figure(figsize=(num_cols * 2.0, num_rows * 2.0))
        for row in range(num_rows):
            for col in range(num_cols):
                index = row * num_cols + col
                plt.subplot(num_rows, num_cols, index + 1)
                plt.imshow(generated_images[index])
                plt.axis("off")

        plt.tight_layout()

        if write_to_file:
            if not os.path.exists(output_dir):
                os.makedirs(output_dir)
            if epoch is not None:
                filename = os.path.join(
                    output_dir, "image_epoch_{:04d}.png".format(epoch)
                )
            else:
                import time

                timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
                filename = os.path.join(output_dir, "image_{}.png".format(timestr))
            plt.savefig(filename)
        else:
            plt.show()

        plt.close()
```

### Training

Stays the same but added some comments

```py
# create and compile the model
model = DiffusionModel(image_size, widths, block_depth)

num_epochs=20

# below tensorflow 2.9:
# pip install tensorflow_addons
# import tensorflow_addons as tfa
# optimizer=tfa.optimizers.AdamW
model.compile(
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.experimental.AdamW(
        learning_rate=learning_rate, weight_decay=weight_decay
    ),
    loss=keras.losses.mean_absolute_error#keras.losses.binary_crossentropy,
)
# pixelwise mean absolute error is used as loss

# save the best model based on the validation KID metric
checkpoint_path = "checkpoints/diffusion_model"
checkpoint_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
    filepath=checkpoint_path,
    save_weights_only=True,
    monitor="val_kid",
    mode="min",
    save_best_only=True,
)

# Wrapped in a try catch for custom architectures that do not have it
try:
    # calculate mean and variance of training dataset for normalization
    model.normalizer.adapt(x_train)
except AttributeError:
    pass

# run training and plot generated images periodically
model.fit(
    x_train,
    #batch_size=batch_size, # do not use when using a tf.dataset
    epochs=num_epochs,
    validation_data=x_test,
    validation_freq=1, # as said validation is slow, you might want to increase this
    callbacks=[
        keras.callbacks.LambdaCallback(on_epoch_end=model.plot_images),
        checkpoint_callback,
    ],
)
```

### Result after 20 epochs

For the image I used `repeat=1`

---

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your post. I am asking the question whether the learning network can be simplified - not to make the Keras example work with MNIST.  We all know that diffusion works as presented with u-net. But It seems like diffusion only works with u-net.

Comment: @EdvBeq parts of your problems were hidden in the diffusion implementation, this is why we on SO review the whole problem not only what the question directly asks for :-) We have curated your code, so now I will try to find something simpler.

Comment: @MaciejSkorski Absolutely, thank you for pointing those problems out. I corrected the denorm method - and I have no trouble running it fast on gpu but still no convergence.

Comment: Let's see. I will also explore **lighter U-Net alternatives**, I understand this is what you are interested in? Note that in the literature U-Net is considered somewhat simple :-) https://cs230.stanford.edu/projects_fall_2018/reports/12449642.pdf
But there are cheaper alternatives, for instance, this paper does the comparison https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.06840#:~:text=ENet%20was%20less%20accurate%20than,times%20faster%20than%20UNet%20one. 
The code I shared on Kaggle indeed shows that your original network doesn't work. I guess it simply inadequate. This has to be a good architecture.

Comment: @MaciejSkorski I just want to fundamentally understand why we need some "image segmentation" architecture for this problem to work. The papers you listed it appears that they all deal with u-net like architectures.

Comment: @EdvBeq at the very least, you need a noise-predicting network (> the line calling network in DifussionModel) + you need to feedback it on noise variances (> sinusoidal embeddings in DifussionModel). Your original example didn't meet these requirements, I think. In the notebook that I shared I tried some simples models, but performance was not good (pseudo-digits in the output :-)). I will go back to you once I explore it a little more.

Answer (score 0):

My hypothesis：

I think your problem may be caused by [dead neuron problem](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/5706/what-is-the-dying-relu-problem-in-neural-networks) of ReLU. Since your network is shallow, I do not think skip connection is necessary.

My suggestion for verifying my hypothesis:

1. Check for dead neurons. Possible useful link: [how-to-check-for-dead-relu-neurons](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/18810), [How to monitor dead relus](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42362542/9758790)
2. Replace ReLU with LeakyReLU.
3. Add a Batch Normalization layer. Or use the activation fucntion SELU, which somehow contains normalization itself.

Currently I do not have time to verify my hypothesis. Maybe I will return to this question later.